# Screen command keypress Ctrl+r?

Tags: gnu-screen

This is example of the command:

```
 screen -S dua -X stuff $'commandhere'
```

I've searched lots of resources but still not found the command for keypress <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: All screen keystrokes are after a prefix (Ctrl-a by default), so do you mean `C-a C-r`?

Comment: I mean `Ctrl+R` jut like pressing `Ctrl+C` when copying text

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to make `C-R` execute that command, or are you asking about what `C-R` does in `screen`?

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `bash` shell the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> invokes the build-in command `reverse-search-history (C-r)`. Here is the section from the `man 1 bash` or you can find at [bash(1): GNU Bourne-Again SHell - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

```
reverse-search-history (C-r)

    Search backward starting at the current line and moving 'up' through 
    the history as necessary. This is an incremental search.
```

The only other command which maybe invoked is a `screen` specific one for line wrapping, but it's normally invoked like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd>. The description is from `man screen` or from [Screen User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Wrap).

```
Command: wrap state

    (C-a r, C-a C-r)
    Sets the line-wrap setting for the current window. When line-wrap is on,
    the second consecutive printable character output at the last column of a
    line will wrap to the start of the following line. As an added feature, 
    backspace (^H) will also wrap through the left margin to the previous 
    line. Default is ‘on’.
```